# Type Internal compiler error / Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-neon

When entering this code in Eclipse :
Error in the first line "p" underlined with red, i didn't write the whole code because it's pretty big

```
package be.maximvdw.qaplugin.modules;

import be.maximvdw.qaplugin.api.AIModule;
import be.maximvdw.qaplugin.api.AIQuestionEvent;
import be.maximvdw.qaplugin.api.QAPluginAPI;
import be.maximvdw.qaplugin.api.ai.*;
import be.maximvdw.qaplugin.api.annotations.*;
import be.maximvdw.qaplugin.api.exceptions.FeatureNotEnabled;
import be.maximvdw.qaplugin.modules.utils.HtmlUtils;
import be.maximvdw.qaplugin.modules.utils.ItemData;
import be.maximvdw.qaplugin.modules.utils.LocaleDownloader;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.EventPriority;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryClickEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerQuitEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Recipe;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.*;
....
```

I get the following error :

> Internal compiler error: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BaseTypeBinding cannot be
>   cast to org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ReferenceBinding at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.cachePartsFrom(BinaryTypeBinding.java:490) RecipeModule.java   /recipe/src/be/maximvdw/qaplugin/modules    line
>   0 Java Problem

and this :

> Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'Java
>   Builder' on project 'recipe'.
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BaseTypeBinding cannot be
>   cast to org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ReferenceBinding

I'm using Eclipse Neon 4.6.3 / Java 8

Comment: Is this reproducable? Even after restart of Eclipse?

Comment: Affirmative. Also there is this " Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jdt.ui" "

Comment: Hello Alaa zorkane, Read this link may be help full https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=239167

Comment: Did you try cleaning your workspace and starting with 'eclipse -clean'?

Comment: Tried it, same problem.

Comment: Is this code *actually* **in** the package structure you have declared at the top?

Comment: Affirmative, It's **in** the package "be.maximvdw.qaplugin.modules".